# Is there a collective term for all entities that incur Karma?

Tags: karma

Certainly humans, and it looks like animals are part of the Karmic progression - like in the Gajendra story.

does this list of Karma-bound entities vary by different traditions?

Comment: Yes - Jivas / Jivatmas

Answer (score 4):

**Some of the entities that one can be born as due to karma are enumerated in the *[Manusmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202219.html)*:**

> I am now going to describe, briefly, in due order, those migratory
>   states into which one falls through each quality from among
>   these.—(39)
>
> Those partaking of ‘Sattva’ reach the state of the gods, those endowed
>   with ‘Rajas,’ the state of men, and those characterised by ‘Tamas,’
>   the state of beasts; such is the threefold migratory state.—(40)
>
> This threefold Migratory State due to the qualities should be
>   understood to be again of three kinds each—high, low and middling, in
>   accordance with the peculiar character of the act and knowledge of
>   each man.—(41)
>
> Inanimate beings, worms, insects, fishes, snakes, tortoise, cattle and
>   wild animals,—represent the lowest state due to the quality of
>   ‘Tamas.’—(42)
>
> Elephants, horses, despised Śūdras, Mlecchas, lions, tigers and
>   boars—represent the middling state due to the quality of ‘Tamas.’—(43)
>
> Cāraṇas, Suparṇas, hypocritical men, Rākṣasas, and Piśācas—represent
>   the highest state among those partaking of the quality of
>   ‘Tamas.’—(44)
>
> Stick-fencers, wrestlers, actors, men subsisting by the use of
>   weapons, those addicted to gambling and drinking,—represent the lowest
>   state among those partaking of the quality of ‘Rajas.’—(45)
>
> Kings, Kṣatriyas, priests of kings, and leading wranglers and warriors
>   represent the middling state among those partaking of ‘Rajas.’—(46)
>
> Gandharvas, Guhyakas, ‘Yakṣas,’ the attendants of the gods, and all
>   the Apsaras, represent the high state among those partaking of
>   ‘Rajas.’—(47)
>
> Ascetics and hermits, Brāhmaṇas, celestial beings, lunar asterisms,
>   and Daityas represent the first state partaking of ‘Sattva.’—(48)
>
> Sacrificers, sages, gods, vedas, luminaries, years, Pitṛs and Sādhyas
>   represent the second state partaking of ‘Sattva.’—(49)
>
> Brahmā, creators of the universe, Dharma, the Great One,
>   Unmanifest,—these the wise ones describe as representing the best
>   state partaking of ‘Sattva.’—(50)

From another scripture:

> Yājñavalkya (3.137-138).—‘Addicted to bad acts, impatient, active,
>   attached to objects of sense, a man abounds in the attribute of Rajas,
>   and is re-born among men. Lethargic, cruel in bis acts, covetous,
>   heretic, addicted to begging, careless, of bad character, a man
>   abounds in the attribute of Tamas, and is born among animals.’